# Can I use mysql to store images and load them to my ios app?

Tags: mysql, swift, database, xcode, sqlite

I am new to using StackOverflow and I don't know how to properly ask this question also this is my first time using swift and some external database server.

I am creating an ios app using Xcode and I'm attempting to create an inventory to store items (300 - 1000 items) such as milk, eggs, bread etc and will have to store the product image as well as the product details such as weight, price, ingredients etc.

But I have no idea as to what to use I was thinking mysql but after doing some research I've found its best not to use blob. I've already used MySQL for the login page into the app so I assumed it was easier to use mysql for the product database as well.

The idea is the user creates an account, logs in then can view products in my made up store. I wanted to use an external database so I can give the app to friends and they can use it by downloading from the app store when it's finished.

Comment: First problem: "I don't know how to properly ask this question". If you go to "Ask Question" you encounter this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Storing large chunks of binary data in your database is probably a bad plan. Look at using an object store (e.g. [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)) and storing a reference to that in your database.

Comment: Upload images directly to your server with URLSession.

Answer (score 2):

Can you save the bytes of a large file in a database? Yes. Should you? No.

Generally speaking the proper way to handle files in a database is to store the URL of the file, not the file itself.

If the images you're using are available online and you are only need to view them, you only need to save the URL itself. There are libraries that can handle all the downloading and cacheing quite easily once you have the URLs.

If you still need to have the images locally, Save them to disk and store those local File URLs in your database.